# Is it possible to pause/resume a gif animation using FFImageLoading in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, ffimageloading

The question says it all. Upon loading a .gif using either SvgCachedImage or CachedImage it immediately starts playing. I however need to be able to start and stop it according to some logic. Unfortunately, the built in Xamarin Image whilst allowing this takes so way too long to load the 1.2mb .gif that it destroys the user experience.

I have looked through all the properties on CachedImage and SvgCachedImage and cannot find any that may relate to this feature.

Comment: The standard Image control has an IsPlaying property

Comment: It does. However, my missive clearly shows why I moved away from the standard control, it is so slow it cannot meet user expectations. 6 seconds to load a gif?

Comment: Sadly, this issue could be found and unsolved on Github: [Programmatically Start/Stop gif animation?](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1348). You could follow up this issue.

Comment: as of now trying to port to maui, and ffimageloading is not supported there anyway. probably a lot of my issues could be solved if the built in image class exposed the underlying image it has loaded.

Comment: I agree. And have you tried any other tools such as [SKLottie](https://skia.org/docs/user/modules/skottie/) which could control the start and stop of gif?

Comment: I did indeed switch to Lottie. It is not without some issues of it's own though, position and sizing of them is a mess. I got it to work for me in the end but it seems as though they didn't get the sizing right in xamarin. Far better to control it using Scaling rather than trying to set size.  On the plus side i finally got some basic features of animation, i/e stopping and starting them, working in 2022